# can't change function.name in VS Code with node.js

Tags: javascript

I learned that I can change the name property of the function this way but it doesn't work. What did I wrong? Thanks in advance.

```js
const tFunc = a => a**2;

console.log(tFunc.name);

tFunc.name = 'cruella';

console.log(tFunc.name);
```

Comment: Might be worth reading over Mozilla's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name, the name property for a function isn't writable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name):

> A Function object's read-only name property indicates the function's name as specified when it was created, or it may be either anonymous or '' (an empty string) for functions created anonymously.

It is a read only property. You can't change it.